# Android studio: VLC sdk:2.0.6 player release make app not responding

Tags: java, android

I also Using "de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"

I have problem when release player and close window. This action make app not responding long time. Please help:

```
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (libvlc == null)
        return;
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
    vout.removeCallback(cls_H264_Camera.this);
    vout.detachViews();
    holder = null;
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    libvlc.release();
    libvlc = null;

    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
}
```

Debug Logged:

I/MediaCodec: [flush]line:941 [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC]+++ E/NdkMediaCodec: sf error code: -38 E/VLC: [0000007f62245988/7865] mediacodec decoder: AMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer failed I/MediaCodec: [stop]line:616 [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC]+++ I/ACodec: freeBuffersOnPort portIndex 0 I/ACodec: freeBuffersOnPort portIndex 1 E/VLC: [0000007f60ad1d08/7851] core vout display: Failed to change zoom

Comment: Did you find any solution?